# Pointers Values

Tags: c++, pointers

Well pointers is quite a confusing topic but I am enjoying learning it, though sometimes programming takes a toll on me. Anyhow I was practicing some question and got stuck on this one. Can you please explain the output of the below code.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void change(int *b,int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;++i)
        *(b+i)=*(b+i)+5;
}
int main()
{
    int a[]={2,4,6,8,10};
    int i;
    change(a,5);
    for(i=0;i<=4;++i)
        cout<<a[i]<<"\n";

}
```

Here in the function change the statement in the for loop gives me a problem. In this assignment statement on the left hand side `*(b+i)`is storing the value of `*(b+1)+5` but how come a value store another value as `*(b+i)` gives a value every time say for the first iteration `i is 0` which makes the expression  `*(b+0)=*(b+0)+5`  . So LHS here is 7 while RHS is 2,which gives 2=7. Shouldn't it give an error like lvalue required or something like that..?

Comment: Side: The top link in the Related list to the right of this question may prove educational. And your code invokes *undefined behavior*. The last iteration through your loop writes and reads from memory one element beyond your declared size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++, `*(b+x)` is syntactic lemon <sup>(a)</sup> for:

```
b[x]
```

so you should read it with that in mind. In other words, the statement you're asking the question about would be better written as:

```
b[i] = b[i] + 5;
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> The opposite of syntactic sugar, obviously. So named because, while syntactic sugar is an easier to read equivalent, syntactic lemon is *harder* to read.

Unless your mind is, like mine, so warped from years of exposure to C, that it easily takes this sort of stuff in stride :-)

Answer (score 1):

The result of the `*` operator is always an *lvalue* so the assignment is legal.

The result of `*` is [a reference to] the object being pointed to by its operand, not just the value of the object.

Read `*(b + 0) = *(b + 0) + 5` as "the object at location `b + 0` gets the value of the object at `b + 0` plus `5`.

(As an aside, the reason that the second `b + 0` is treated is a value is because it is used in an expression context (as an operand of the arithmetic operator `+`) where its value is required, not because it is the result of applying a dereference operator which, as mentioned above, results in an lvalue. This "treat as a value" artifact is known as an "lvalue-to-rvalue conversion" and happens implicitly wherever required.)

Comment: `The result of the * operator is always an lvalue so the assignment is legal.` Is this always true even in the below example                                                                                                      int a=10,*b;                                                                                                     b=&a;                                                                                                           cout<<*b; // But is nt here it just gave the r value

Comment: So you are saying that in the above code there was an implicit lvalue to rvalue conversion rt?

Comment: Yes, there's an implicit lvalue to rvalue conversion on `*b` in `cout << *b` but there would also be one on `a` (another lvalue) in `cout << a`.

Answer (score 0):

As paxdiablo noted, this is basically just intentionally badly written code (maybe to test or increase your understanding of C++ syntax).

First, what change(int *b,int n) does:

As noted, `*(a+i)` gives the value at "pointer a, increased by i steps". So what change() does is the following: It loops over all values for i from 0 to just below n (for-loop) and executes

`*(b+i)=*(b+i)+5;`

This latter statement means: take the value at "pointer b, increased by i steps", and then ASSIGN to it (nothing to do with equality testing!) the value that can be found at "pointer b, increased by i steps", increased by 5.

What it does in short is to loop over an int-array b[] of length n (addressed in C-style by its base pointer address b), and increase all contained integers by 5.

The rest of the main program just outputs the changed values onto the console.

If the practice questions in the source you are using to learn C++ are all similar to this, I would suggest maybe switching to a different course, if possible. While understanding syntax is important, there are other concepts that are at least as important in modern object-oriented programming (like, proper use of libraries, inheritance, code maintainability, ...).